# Adding to dictionary in a loop while reading file

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am wondering if there is a simple way to add dictionaries in a for loop while reading a file.
I have a file.txt which i want to read it line by line and then add them into a dictionary. 
I tried the below but not able to actually add all the lines as key:value in the same dictionary.

```
content of file.txt
name1:value1
name2:value2
name3:value3


 with open("file.txt", 'r') as fd:
        for line in fd.readlines():
            d=dict([line.rstrip().split(":")])
            d.update(d)
```

Ultimately, i want my dictionary to have something like this:
d = {'Name1': 'Value1', 'Name2': 'Value2', 'Name3': 'Value3'}

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a sample line from the txt file?

Comment: Sorry didn't see the first 4 line

Comment: You got some lines but not all? `dict` doesn't allow duplicate keys so if a name repeats itself the old line is overwritten.

Comment: a simple dictionary comprehension will do it: `{k:v for line in fd for k, v in (line.strip().split(':'))}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On each iteration of the loop, you create a `dict` called `d`, try to update it with itself and then discard it. Since `dict` takes a sequence at initialization time, you can create it in one step

```
with open("file.txt", 'r') as fd:
    d = dict(line.rstrip().split(":") for line in fd)
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to declare the dict outside of the loop and update it inside. this is a scope issue.

```
 d={}
 with open("file.txt", 'r') as fd:
    for line in fd.readlines():
        d_tmp=dict([line.rstrip().split(":")])
        d.update(d_tmp)
```

Answer (score 3):

No need to call 'readlines', file objects support the iter protocol. Calling 'readlines' will pull the whole file into memory

```
>>> d = {}
>>> with open('var.txt') as myfile:
...     for line in myfile:
...         name, val = line.split(':')
...         d[name] = val
... 
>>> d
{'name2': 'value2\n', 'name1': 'value1\n'}
```

You can drop the line returns on the dictionary values by doing:

```
d[name] = val.strip()
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't know about val.strip! Does this also drop new lines?

Comment: Derp, yeah, I meant newlines, not line returns. I'll nuke the '\n' by default, or you can pass in what ever you want to strip from the front & back of the string.

Comment: Lol, so by default it only strips the \n from the line? Is there a built in method that removes the \r?

Comment: If you're using Python 3, that's not a thing to worry about; all newlines will be converted to just '\n' auto-magically. In Python 2, just open('myfile.txt', 'rU') to get the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the most efficient but it works! Good luck!!!

```
def createDict(fileName):
    '''
        Returns a dict of fileName
        '''
    data = {} #init dict
    file = open(fileName, 'rb').readlines() #open File and create list of each line
    for i in file: #loop through each file
        i = i.replace('\r', '').replace('\n', '').split(':') #replace all instances of \n and \r and split at :
        data[i[0]] = i[1] #add values to dict
    return data #return dict
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution (it looks clearer to me):

```
>>> with open("sample", 'r') as fd:
...  for line in fd.readlines():
...   row = line.rstrip().split(":")
...   d[row[0]] = row[1]
... 
>>> d
{'name3': 'value3', 'me1': 'value1', 'name2': 'value2'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fancy one liner assuming the file always exists and readable.

```
>>> dict(line.rstrip().split(':') for line in open('file.txt'))

{'name2': 'value2', 'name3': 'value3', 'name1': 'value1'}
```

Comment: No need to create an intermediate list.